# MFC: How do you print contents of a CRichEditView?

Tags: printing, mfc, richedit

I have a simple task where I need to print the contents of a CRichEditView.  No scaling needed, No print range, just print contents.   Keeping it simple, I tried adding this to the message map:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CRichEditView::OnFilePrint)
```

And implementing the virtual function:

```
BOOL CMyRichView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}
```

But when it printed (this is what was actually to be printed):

```
BOOL CMyRichView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}
```

I only got half of the 'r' on return "eturn DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);".  So it seems it must have to do with margins or something that the `CRichEditView` doesn't handle itself?

What am I missing?

TIA!!

EDIT:

I tried changing it to

```
BOOL CMyRichView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  // note a MM_TWIPS is 1/1440 of an inch.

  // create 1/2" margin which most printers support
  CSize sizepaper = GetPaperSize();
  CRect rectmargins(720, 720, sizepaper.cx - 720, sizepaper.cy - 720);

  // Need to set the margins when printing from CRichEditView
  SetMargins(rectmargins);

  // per SetMargins API reference, call wrapchanged 
  if (m_nWordWrap==WrapToTargetDevice) {
    WrapChanged();
  }

  return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}
```

But now it just spits out tons of blank pieces of paper.  I also tried it within the virtual function `OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)` prior to calling the base class.  Same result, so deleted `OnPrint()` (not using it).

EDIT:

So I took that sample above from the `GetPaperSize()` documentation.  But it was wrong.  It works using this (which the documentation for `SetPaperSize()` uses).

```
BOOL CMyRichView::OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  // note a MM_TWIPS is 1/1440 of an inch.

  // Need to set the margins when printing from CRichEditView
  SetMargins(CRect(720, 720, 720, 720));

  // per SetMargins API reference, call wrapchanged 
  if (m_nWordWrap==WrapToTargetDevice) {
    WrapChanged();
  }

  return __super::OnPrint(pDC, pInfo);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown printing code.

Comment: That's it.   It's a CRichEditView control, it supposed to handle all the details.

Comment: Change to `SetMargins(CRect(720, 720, 720, 720));` , X2 and Y2 values are margins, not width and height. Try calling this function in `OnInitialUpdate()` Give some information about the project. Did you make it with the Wizard? Do you see a print dialog?

Comment: I had added the last edit above which did that and fixed it .. the mfc docs had one sample correct and one wrong.

Comment: Why not add your own answer with your explanation and working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CRichEditView::OnFilePrint)


BOOL CMyRichView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}

BOOL CMyRichView::OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
  // note a MM_TWIPS is 1/1440 of an inch.

  // Need to set the margins when printing from CRichEditView
  SetMargins(CRect(720, 720, 720, 720));

  // per SetMargins API reference, call wrapchanged 
  if (m_nWordWrap==WrapToTargetDevice) {
    WrapChanged();
  }

  return __super::OnPrint(pDC, pInfo);
}
```